# Get Git History in Google Cloud Build Step

Tags: google-cloud-build, nrwl-nx

I'm using Google Cloud Build to run CI for my Nx workspace. Here's the cloudbuild.yaml file:

```yaml
    steps:
      - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
        id: Test_Affected_Projects
        entrypoint: 'sh'
        args: [
            '-c',
            'docker build --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=$$NPM_TOKEN --file ./test/Dockerfile.test-runner -t mha-test-runner .']
        secretEnv: ['NPM_TOKEN']
    # Remove the docker image
    secrets:
    - kmsKeyName: /path/to/key
      secretEnv:
        NPM_TOKEN: some_key_value
```

(There are currently two steps, but I removed the second for brevity. The second step just removes the created docker image.)

Now the command inside the Docker image here runs all the tests for the Nx workspace. The thing is, Nx has a great command where only the affected libraries will be tested. But for the command to run, the git history of the project needs to be available.

I've tried to get the git history in the cloud build context, but I haven't been able to get it working. This is the step I added to try and get everything working:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    args: ['fetch', '--unshallow']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    id: Test_Affected_Projects
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args: [
        '-c',
        'docker build --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=$$NPM_TOKEN --file ./test/Dockerfile.test-runner -t mha-test-runner .']
    secretEnv: ['NPM_TOKEN']
# Remove the docker image
secrets:
- kmsKeyName: /path/to/key
  secretEnv:
    NPM_TOKEN: some_key_value
```

That new first command, which should get the git history, fails. The error message says that it's not a git repo, so the command fails.

My question is: how can I get the git history in the cloud build context so that I can use it with different commands in the build/testing process?

Comment: Is the trigger a Github App trigger? If that's the case you must [copy the repo](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/create-manage-triggers#including_the_repository_history_in_a_build) beforehand. The difference between a GitHub trigger and a GitHub App trigger is subtile but the 1st will do the shallow copy of the repo and the 2nd will have Cloud Storage archive as source.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason this isn't working is that you need to store the github credentials in the cloud build environment.

I believe this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-github-from-build) can help.

will allow you to do so, and then you will be able to call the `git fetch --unshallow` as you already have.